OxygenOs (OnePlus) Mute notifications by code
I'm developing an Android app that allows users to enable or disable Do Not Disturb (DND) mode based on their preferences. This feature enables users to switch between different sound profiles depending on their situations (e.g., work, sleep), allowing for tailored notifications such as allowing all calls, all notifications, or just calls while muting notifications. This aligns with the standard DND options available in Android.
However, I've encountered a significant issue with OnePlus devices due to their customized version of Android, called OxygenOS. It introduces a setting called "Mute Notifications," which is separate from the standard DND mode. When I attempt to activate DND programmatically, even with notifications/messages set to not bypass DND, my settings are ignored.
Could someone clarify why manufacturers deviate from Android standards and how this impacts user experience? Additionally, it would be helpful if they provided a public API to modify their specific settings. Any insights or workarounds would be greatly appreciated!
